# Java 8 update 45 - SSL OCSP security issue

Tags: java, security, ssl, https

While launch our JNLP based web start with java 8 update 45, we are getting the below ocsp error on SSL certificate. SSL is issued by a trusted issuer and the hierarchy is

Verisign
  -> Symantec
    -> our application

While verify the network call we have identified the OCSP call is looking up the OCSP: URI: IP of our application alone and then throws the below error, so is there any changed in hierarchy of intermediate certificates in SSL to over come this error.

**Error:**

```
Exception raised in swingToSvlt() :javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.sun.deploy.security.RevocationChecker$StatusUnknownException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: OCSP response error: UNAUTHORIZED
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.sun.deploy.security.RevocationChecker$StatusUnknownException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: OCSP response error: UNAUTHORIZED
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.access$100(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$8.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$8.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
at sub.loader.Factory.swingToSvlt(Factory.java:177)
at sub.client.LoaderClient.getModule(LoaderClient.java:61)`
```